# onAttach() not called with setRetainInstance(true);

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a parent fragment that holds a single child fragment, and both of the fragment's `onAttach` and `onCreateView` methods are logged for debugging purposes.

When I add the parent fragment to the Activity this way:

```
parent.setRetainInstance(false);
```

the output after a rotation is this:

```
07-08 20:10:52.295: E/TAG(14216): Parent's onAttach called!
07-08 20:10:52.295: E/TAG(14216): Parent's onCreateView called!
07-08 20:10:52.305: E/TAG(14216): Child's onAttach called!
07-08 20:10:52.305: E/TAG(14216): Child's onCreateView called!
```

but as retained:

```
parent.setRetainInstance(true);
```

the output (after the rotation) is this:

```
07-08 20:10:55.395: E/TAG(14216): Parent's onAttach called!
07-08 20:10:55.395: E/TAG(14216): Parent's onCreateView called!
07-08 20:10:55.400: E/TAG(14216): Child's onCreateView called!
```

To summarize, child fragment's `onAttach` method won't get called if the parent is a retained fragment (I assume neither `onDetach`). This scenario just a demo, I actually had to debug a complex application to find out what causes the failure. The application had memory issues, because after orientation change, the child fragment leaked the previous Activity (as a listener set in onAttach).

If someone has the same problem, a workaround could be to manually call the children's `onAttach` from the parent fragment's `onAttach`.

**And the question is: Is this a bug?**

Answer (score 2):

When you do a setRetainInstance(true), the fragment retains its configuration (and therefore its reference to the nested fragment, which is never really detached/attached). This can happen, for example, during a configurationChange (like a rotation).

So this is not a bug, it's by Android's design.

To answer your question, you could keep the Activity/Listener reference as a WeakReference so it gets released when it's no longer needed.

On the other hand, I'd rethink the whole idea, seems like you should have an observer pattern here (subscribe/unsubscribe from the listener/observer during onStop/onPause or similar).

<sub>**note:** that doesn't make it better, I loathe Android's lifecycle methods</sub>

Comment: I understand that the configuration is retained, but there is still a new Activity to attach. Not calling the onAttach after rotation is misleading, and would be better if it not called at all. I can call it manually from the parent, so the framework could do it also. I still see this as a bug.

Comment: WeakReference would make the fragment useless after the rotation, because there would not be any listener to call. --> No onAttached called with the new Activity, and the old reference is lost after rotation.

Comment: The parent fragment will have the reference to the new activity in onAttach(), the child fragment can get it from it.